# python read dict with array value

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a `test.yaml`:

```
exclude:
  - name: apple
    version: [3]
  - name: pear
    version: [2,4,5]
```

I have a function to check these values in dict and compare it.

```
def do_something(fruit_name: str, data: dict):
    
    result =[]

    versions = [2,3,5,6,7,8]
    for version in versions:

       url = f"some.api.url/subjects/{fruit_name}/versions/{version}"
       response = sr_rest_api.session.post(url, json=data).json()

       config = read_yaml("test.yaml") # not sure

       for schema in config['exclude']: # not sure

          # I'm stuck here
          # if version and name exist in the yaml, skip
          # else, append to the list such as:
          else:
            result.append(response["is_fruit"]) # Boolean

    return result
```

I'm not sure how to unwrap the array from a dictionary.

Result from reading the yaml:

```
{'exclude': [{'name': 'apple', 'version': [3]},
{'name': 'pear', 'version': [2,4,5]}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `schema` to see its structure and working from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def do_something(fruit_name: str, data: dict):
    
    result =[]

    # do this once outside the loop
    config = read_yaml("test.yaml")

    # make the config exclusions easier to work with
    exclusions = {schema["name"]: schema for schema in config["exclude"]}

    versions = [2,3,5,6,7,8]
    for version in versions:
        if fruit_name in exclusions and version in exclusions[fruit_name]["version"]:
            # this is an excluded fruit version, skip it
            continue
        else:
            # fetch the data and update result
            url = f"some.api.url/subjects/{fruit_name}/versions/{version}"
            response = sr_rest_api.session.post(url, json=data).json()

            result.append(response["is_fruit"])

    return result
```